# Maximum Likelihood Estimation: Multivariate Gaussian function. Matrix calculus

Tags: optimization, matrix-calculus, maximum-likelihood, hessian-matrix

I am reading a paper and trying to understand how the authors estimated the standard errors of a set of parameter estimates $[\delta\ \ \phi \ \ \Sigma]$. Below is the loglikelihood function (sorry I could not typeset):
[image]

where,

[image]

Using the trace trick and the rules of differentiation I managed to derive the first order conditions (after reading [this](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~epxing/Class/10701-08s/recitation/gaussian.pdf)). The authors provided the final results, which helped to verify my results. But I have been unable to derive the second order partial derivatives matrix i.e. Hessian. The authors do not derive the Hessian. I want to estimate the standard errors of the parameter estimates using the Hessian.

Will anyone spare a few minutes to help?

If you know any other method for estimating the standard errors of the parameter estimates, do please explain or provide reference.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Comment: Thank you, I will use the reference next time.

Comment: Just a quick note, although not entirely related with with your question. In reality, one usually does not use Hessian to calculate the likelihood (for an alternative methods, see [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broyden%E2%80%93Fletcher%E2%80%93Goldfarb%E2%80%93Shanno_algorithm), and then derive the Hessian using the numerical method. Furthermore, it can be shown that the standard deviation equals the inverse of Fisher information matrix, the calculation of which is relatively straight forward